# Access IRegionManager Object from a Module ViewModel - Prism with Unity

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-container, prism

I am trying to access the regionManager of the Shell from the Viewmodel  of a module in a WPF-Prism Application with Unity for view-based Navigation

Following is the constructor of the ViewModel for a Module.

```
public LeftSelectionViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
{
     _regionManager = regionManager;                
}
```

Seems can't construct the Viewmodel object(I use auto-wiring).

Works fine when I remove the parameter from the Constructor.

What is missing?

Comment: I am assuming you are getting a ResolutionFailedException stating that namespace.IRegionManager is an interface and cannot be constructed. What is the namespace before IRegionManager in the exception?

Comment: We're using similar approach (but with a different DI container: MEF), this should work. Make sure the region manager is registered in the container.

Comment: I ended up using MEF - part composition